# Web Design for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

What, if any, considerations (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) should you take when designing for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome uses Webkit, the same engine as is used by Safari, OmniWeb, iCab and more. Just code everything based on the standards and verify in each browser.

Answer (score 5):

I think first and foremost you should focus on using HTML and scripting that follows the standards.

After you have that running, file a bug report then make the browser-specific tweaks.  If Chrome is worth a flip you *shouldn't* have to tweak things for it.

Answer (score 4):

The same ones you'd take for Safari, as they share the same rendering engine (with a slight version mismatch).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure filing a bug report really helps with all those IE rendering issues!

Realistically, you need to test your application in each browser, no browser 100% follows the W3C standards so ultimately you can't rely on following that at all. You need to test everything you do in any browser you wish to support.

As has been mentioned, Google Chrome has the same rendering engine as Safari/iPhone/etc., WebKit which passes Acid3, so there should be minimal issues if you follow the standards. But don't rely on it. Google Chrome currently uses a slightly older version of WebKit than Safari. I'm sure they'll eventually be on the same version at some point, but unfortunately any new browser becomes just another browser to test in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you designing specifically *for* Chrome, or do you want to make sure your pages work well with Chrome?

Assuming it's the latter, then just use the same design considerations you'd do for any browser. If applicable, keep in mind that many phones and video game consoles have web browsers now.

Chrome uses a new JavaScript engine, so you'll have to test your JavaScript using Chrome as well as Safari. The HTML and CSS may render pretty much the same, but they use different JavaScript engines.